# What are the default permissions for /root?

Tags: permissions, root, chmod

Not realizing what directory I was in, I did a "chmod 777 ." in /root.
Now I would like to set the permissions for /root back to the default.
Can someone please tell me the correct default permissions for /root?
Should it be 700 ?

Comment: I think file system have permission of 755.

Comment: Your question may be answered anyway - but I found [this](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) a while ago, and it may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drwx------   4 root     root      4096 okt 29 20:00 root
```

Files in `/root/`:

```
drwx------  4 root root 4096 okt 29 20:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 okt 25 22:34 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 okt 28  2012 .bashrc
drwx------  4 root root 4096 okt 29 20:00 .config
drwx------  3 root root 4096 okt 29 20:00 .dbus
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  140 okt 28  2012 .profile
```

Comment: do you need anything from .dbus and/or .config?